# How to make an exceptions in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all: I'm a Jquery newbie :-)

I've implemented this "smooth scroll" effect to the internal links on my website so when I use `#` in a `href` (like a `href="#footer"`) it makes the effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Denne funktion fanger #");
        console.log(event);

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

And I'm using this script to fade between pages so everytime I click an external link it makes the fade effect to that given page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(1000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(1000);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

But I do not want the fade effect on the internal links where I use the smooth scroll effect. How do I write an exception in the above script so it ignores the fade effect-script where I use the `#`?

Thank you!

Comment: Add something to your external links, like a class, then update your jquery to selector to select based of that class

Comment: Just curious, why are you handling document ready 3 separate times?

Comment: Smeegs: As I started out with. I'm a total Jquery newbie! :-) Feel free to write me a clean code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with a "startswith".

```
$("a:not([href^='#'])").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just fitler out the elements.

```
$("a").not("[href^='#']").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
});
```